# Adding multiple stack panels in wrap panel………

Tags: .net, wpf

I have one WrapPanel 
With name `“PageWrapPanel”`
In Main window of  my WPF application

Now I an trying to **add one stack panel  five times in this wrap panel….**

```
StackPanel stkPnl = new StackPanel();
            stkPnl.Width = 300;
            stkPnl.Height = 150;
            stkPnl.Background = Brushes.DarkKhaki;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                PageWrapPanel.Children.Add(stkPnl);
            }
```

**But it does not work….
What is going wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the same element at multiple places in the logical tree. You need to add five identical `StackPanel`s instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    StackPanel stkPnl = new StackPanel();
    stkPnl.Width = 300;
    stkPnl.Height = 150;
    stkPnl.Background = Brushes.DarkKhaki;
    PageWrapPanel.Children.Add(stkPnl);
}
```

BTW, this should be evident from the error message in the exception you are getting ("Specified element is already the logical child of another element."), *which you totally should provide* instead of letting people guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the creation of the StackPanel in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    StackPanel stkPnl = new StackPanel(); 
    stkPnl.Width = 300;
    stkPnl.Height = 150;
    stkPnl.Background = Brushes.DarkKhaki;
    PageWrapPanel.Children.Add(stkPnl);
}
```

Otherwise, you have tried to place the same StackPanel in the WrapPanel more than once, which is where your error comes from.